# What is difference between "so that" and "in order to"?

Tags: word-meaning, difference

What is the difference between "so that" and "in order to" in the following sentences?

> *I am saving money **so that** I can buy a new home.*
> *I am saving money **in order to** buy a new home*.

Is there the slightest difference in meaning?

Answer (score 1):

In OP's *exact* context, there's no difference in meaning. But note that the word ***that*** is effectively *optional*, in the first version. And although...

> 1: *I am saving money **so** I can buy a new home*

...*can* mean exactly the same as...

> 2: *I am saving money **in order to** buy a new home*

...it can ***also*** carry the sense of...

> 3:  *I am saving money **therefore** I can buy a new home*

That's to say, without ***that***, it's possible that I never even *thought* of buying a house when I started saving - I'm simply pointing out that ***because*** I'm saving money, I could buy a house ***if I wanted***.

It's also worth pointing out that ***in order*** is effectively optional in #2 above. It would still mean exactly the same phrased as...

> 4: *I am saving money **to** buy a new home*

Answer (score 0):

"So that" is more casual than "in order to". They both have nearly identical meaning, however.

Source: Native speaker.